# Extending class from NPM package in typescript

Tags: typescript, npm, protractor

I have a **util.ts** file that is imported throughout my project. I installed an npm package that I want to add to my **util.ts**.
**Util.ts:**

```
import helper from "node_modules/helper" //Private package, lets just call it helper
export class util extends helper { //doesn't extend how I would expect
  static utilFunction() { return "test"; }
}
```

In any spec I can call it like:

```
import {util} from "path/to/util"
import {helper} from "node_modules/helper" //dont want to have to do this
describe("Testing stuff",function(){
  it("Should test the thing", function(){
    util.utilFunction();
    util.helperFunction(); //What I am trying to do
    helper.helperFunction(); //What is currently working but I want to avoid
  });
});
```

Part of helper package that is installed:

```
export class helper{
  public static helperFunction{ return "test helper"; }
}
```

I can call any function from my helper npm package by importing it and calling it like:
`helper.helperFunction()`   But I would like to be able to call its functions through **util.ts**
Basically the npm package will supplement my current utils, and I don't want to have to call/import them separately. How can I extend the npm package?

Comment: Is the `helper` a class? If not, I don't know if you can extend from something that's not a class.

Comment: @francium I added an part from helper

Comment: Are you sure the helper code isn't compiled down into some other form? Are you sure that the code you're trying to import is indeed the code that's being imported. It's just that sometimes npm packages will contain the original source, but the version you actually import is a compiled/minified version which doesn't look a lot like the original. Suppose a class is compiled down into prototype functions, then I don't know if you're able to import that using the class notation, I haven't ever tried that.

Comment: After testing it out, it appear the the `class extends` will work as expected with function prototypes. Example https://jsfiddle.net/cks65af2/1/ Open console and see console log outputs.